# Create pdf from Illustrator and retain scale when printing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, pdf, scale

I have created a pattern in Illustrator CS6 and need to save as a pdf and retain the correct scale. I'm losing 1/16" of a inch all around. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Hi G.Peppers, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your PDF save settings to ensure it is saving at 100% scale, and that the document bleed is not being included. Might be worth checking print settings to to ensure no bordering is being added, or that it is set too.

Comment: Thanks @SimonCurry, those are helpful suggestions. I changed the setting from "Actual Size" to "Custom 100%" in Acrobat Pro and that worked but still need to check what you mentioned. Thanks again.